# Gradle: extend DLS of existing type

Tags: java, c++, gradle, dsl

I would like to add a function to existant types, in my case this is `NativeLibrarySpec`.

I tried with [gradle extensions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html) and it is aboutly working yet but now I want to generalize it for being able to use it like if it was a standard functionality of the DSL of `NativeLibrarySpec`.
The problem is that I can access the instance only after its configuration (the block containing my function) and so it fails because it tries to call `specialConfig` before I am able to link it...

Here is the code (do not care about the fact this example is for native software C++):

```
// File: build.gradle
apply plugin: 'cpp'

class SpecialConfig {
    NativeComponentSpec componentSpec

    SpecialConfig(NativeComponentSpec componentSpec) {
        this.componentSpec = componentSpec
    }

    def something(boolean enabled) {
        componentSpec.sources {
            cpp {
                // Some important stuffs
            }
        }
    }
}

model {
    components {
        main(NativeLibrarySpec) {
            // How to bring this out ??
            project.extensions.create('specialConfig', SpecialConfig, it)

            // This is the new functionality I want to use
            specialConfig {
                something(true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an other example but it will only work from project.*
https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-goodness-extending-dsl

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this please

```
plugins {
    id 'cpp'
}

class SpecialConfig {
    // no need to pass this to the constructor we can just make it a
    // method arg instead
    SpecialConfig() {
    }

    // manipulate spec as desired
    def something(NativeComponentSpec spec, boolean enabled) {
        println "Hello something!"
        spec.sources {
            cpp {
                // Some important stuffs
            }
        }
    }
}

// add your extension earlier
project.extensions.create('specialConfig', SpecialConfig)
model {
    components {
        main(NativeLibrarySpec) { mySpec ->
            // we can call our extension via the project
            project.specialConfig { config ->
                // our closure is handed an instance of the class
                // on that we can call methods
                config.something(mySpec, true)
            }
            // or more simply we could make it a one liner
            project.specialConfig.something(mySpec, true)
        }
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
$ gradle build
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Hello something!
:linkMainSharedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:mainSharedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:createMainStaticLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:mainStaticLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:check UP-TO-DATE
:build UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.104 secs
```

Comment: Thank you for your time :) Unfortunately I am looking for a way to do it without having to pass any parameters, the code should look fluent